# Finding a matrix inverse when an equation involving it is a multiple of the identity matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

Say you had a matrix $A$, and you did an equation like $A^2 - A$, and proved that it was a multiple of $I$.  How could you find $A^{-1}$ in the form $rA + sI$ after proving that?

I want to do it myself, which is why I didn't provide the matrix, but I don't know where to go.  I know that for a matrix to be invertible, the determinant can't be 0, but I don't think that connects to it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A^2-A=aI$, with $a\ne0$; then (assuming $A^{-1}$ exists)
$$
A^{-1}(aI)=A^{-1}(A^2-A)
$$
or
$$
aA^{-1}=A-I
$$
Then it's easy to close the circle.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take the equation $A^2 - A = kI$ and multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$. Then, solve for $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Well, the only difference seems to be in $k$ in place of $a$.

Comment: @egreg there's also the fact that yours was 15 seconds earlier